# Selenium in IE tab

Tags: selenium, gui-test-framework

Did anyone use selenium in IE tab plugin for firefox. I am not able to record actions in selenium IDE.

Answer (score 2):

Selenium IDE is Firefox add-on, not IE add-on. It doesn't work when you switch to IE mode.